# 2012 Toyota Tacoma won't shift into Reverse

Tags: toyota, troubleshooting, automatic-transmission

I've just had my 2012 Tacoma towed to the dealership due to the truck not shifting into reverse correctly. I first noticed a problem when I was driving home and the RPMs would get up to between 3 and 4 and it felt as if the gears weren't changing properly. I shifted back into neutral and then into drive again and everything seemed to be going fine.

Then I pulled into a parking spot and later attempted to put it in reverse and pull out. The truck acts like it's in neutral when put in reverse (I can put the gear shift in reverse but the gear is not changing).

What could be going wrong?

More information:

- 2WD 6 cyl
- Truck is < 1 year old
- Has ~ 14,000 miles on it
- Has had regular scheduled maintenance on time for the last year.

**Update:** The tow truck guy just called and said that he "jerked" the truck while it was attached to the chain on the tow and was able to put it in reverse. I'll still have the dealership look at it tomorrow.

**Update 2**: Yep, the entire transmission is being replaced.

Comment: It has been a couple years, but I would like to know...how has your Tacoma been running? I have a 2014 Tacoma and the same thing happened to me last night. I only have 3,500 miles on it! Did you continue to have problems after they replaced the transmission? Did any thing else in the drive train fail?

Comment: Been running great after getting a new transmission, no problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The transmission is malfunctioning, cut and dry. If it's 1 year old, sit back and let the dealership replace it.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of, although I guess I'd rather that fail *now* while its still under warranty.

Comment: It's unusual that this would happen with so few miles. If it happens again after the dealership repairs it, consider looking into what lemon laws there are in South Carolina.

Comment: @MarkJohnson: Definitely. Latest update is that the transmission is being completely replaced. What a pain@

Comment: So the transmission was replaced and now everything is going smoothly. I tried to get more details on what could have gone wrong but apparently the dealership sends the transmission to Toyota so even they don't know what went wrong.